# Is there a way to loop through an array and add instructions and execute it very fast? (python)

Tags: python

I am currently working on a data set that needs to know the gap between a value on an array and the value below it then divide the result with current array value

For example :

```
result = 0
arr = [...]
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if i > 0:
        result += (arr[i] - arr[i - 1]) / arr[i]
```

But I would like to do this, in a "one-liner" scenario and preferably without any loops as to optimize performance, are there any ways to do this?

---

for example I am looking for something like :

```
arr = list(range(min, max))
```

is equivalent to :

```
arr = []
for i in range(max - min):
    arr.append(i + min)
```

My apologies if this is a noob-ish question, but I hope you can help me :)

Comment: And is equivalent to:  arr = [i + min for i in range(max - min)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a use-case for [numpy](https://numpy.org/) (or generally anything supporting vectorized computation in python - maybe tensorflow would work too?)

```
import numpy as np
np_array = np.asarray(arr)
result = np.sum((np_array[1:]-np_array[:-1])/np_array[1:])
```

If the [1:] and such notation above is unclear, take a moment to learn about [python slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing).

**EDIT:** On the topic of speed - numpy (or any vectorized approach) is generally faster than the iterative approach. If for some reason speed is very important, [cupy](https://cupy.dev/) should be even faster, although this will need to use the machine's GPU.

Answer (score 1):

np.diff is what you want:

```py
import numpy as np
np_result = np.sum(np.diff(arr) / arr[1:])

np.testing.assert_almost_equal(np_result, result)
```

Using timeit and an initial array of

```py
np.random.seed(1)
arr = np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=(10000,))
```

we get for the non-vectorized code:

```
3.59 ms ± 68.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

and for the vectorized code:

```
33.2 µs ± 922 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

EDIT: @Xavi's indexed, [no diff solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73135189/837451) is marginally faster:

```
29.7 µs ± 802 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

30 microseconds is 0.03 milliseconds, so it's a speedup of approx 100x, which is what we would expect for a trivially vectorizable operation.

Comment: Thanks for benchmarking my solution too! I assume the slight overhead comes from how most standard numpy functions have some extra functionality that their implementation has to account for with some checks ([see here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.23.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L1319-L1449)). That being said, it's better practice to use descriptive functions (such as diff) - I only avoided it for the sake of keeping it simple.